# Objective-C : (private / public properties) making a property readonly for outside class calls and readwrite for self calls

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Would you know a way to make a property readonly for outside calls and readwrite for inside calls ?

I've read times ago somthing that seemed like

In the .h

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSDate* theDate;
```

In the .m

```
@interface TheClassName()
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate* theDate;
@end
```

but this raises a warning when compiling the .m "Property theDate attribute in TheClassName class continuation does not match class TheClassName property".

Anyway, it seems to work (can read but not set from outside the class, can do both from inside) but I should have missed somehting to avoid the warning.
Or if you know a better way to do this...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In your .h:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSDate* theDate;
```

In your .m:

```
@interface TheClassName()
@property(nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSDate* theDate;
@end
```

Comment: +1, might also want to drop the `readwrite` as that’s the default and `nonatomic` until that’s really needed?

Comment: The `readwrite` makes it explicit that you know exactly what you want.  Some folks are carrying over the "always use `nonatomic`" mantra from iOS to Cocoa (I certainly do);   it may be a project wide policy.

Comment: Also;  the reason why `retain` must be mentioned in both places is that the codegen for `@synthesis` of the getter of `retain` vs. `assign` can be different in certain cases.  Thus, the policy of `retain` on the readonly view of the property *is* a part of the class's API/contract.

Comment: I just did this and wanted to assure that it's right. Now I'm sure :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This issue is largely eliminated if you're moving to ARC. Instead of two property declarations, you'd declare it once in the header.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSDate* theDate;
```

And then in the class extension, simply declare a __strong instance variable.

```
@interface TheClassName()
{
    __strong NSDate* _theDate;
}
@end
```

And synthesize them appropriately in the implementation

```
@implementation TheClassName
@synthesize theDate = _theDate;
```

Now you can set the instance variable.

```
_theDate = [NSDate date];
```

And ARC will magically inline the appropriate retain/release functionality into your code to treat it as a strong/retained variable. This has the advantage of being faster than the old style (retain) properties as well as ARC inlines the retain/release code at compile time.

Comment: You can also leave the _ off the iVar name in this case since self.theDate will raise a warning as no getter was synthesized and __strong prevents you from having to worry about unsafely setting the iVar directly by mistake.

Comment: but what, if i want the setter or getter perform additional tasks, ie broadcast notifications, sanity check?

Comment: Then you declare the property, and write whatever getter or setter method you need, the __strong declaration will prevent you from having to implement any retain/release logic in the setter.

Comment: you dindt get, what I want to say: if you use property calls consequently, you have a higher degree of cleanness and abstraction.

Answer (score -1):

If the property is backed by a variable, the variable is read-write from inside the class be default. Make the property read-only, and your design goal will be met. Inside the class, refer to the variable without prepending `self.`.

Comment: -1: There are many very good reasons to use accessors even when referencing one's own instance variables. (Memory management is one.) Oliver's question is valid.

Answer (score -2):

In the .m, you shouldn't put @property again. I'm not sure what effect that has, though.
Did you mean to use @synthesize?

Note that theDate will be read/write inside the class implementation anyway, regardless of being readonly to the outside world.

Comment: he is using an class extension. this can be used for private properties, that just can be called on `self` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464112/best-practice-for-condensing-code/4465573#4465573

Comment: It's not clear if that's what Oliver is trying to achieve, but if it is, then that's a good answer. Vikingosegundo, you should put that as an answer, and Oliver can accept it!

Comment: he is asking, how to achieve a public read-only property, while there is another private property with read-write access. I never did such a thing. I just explained you, that he is using an class extension, but it doesn't answer the question.