# Set custom font as default in iphone programming

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I'm building an App that requires a custom font. I added the form to my info.plist and I can use it connecting each single object (labels, textviews. table cells.... ) manually to an IBOUtlet and them set the font in the initialization.

Nevertheless this process is long, inefficient and probably bad done.

Could somebody tell me if I can setup a font by default for all the app?

Comment: May I ask if you intentionally used the `iphone-sdk-4.0` tag **specifically**? Or, is iOS5 an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In iOS 5** this is easy:

[Set a default font for whole iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app)

**Prior to iOS 5** if you're doing this throughout your app, I'd **subclass** `UILabel` and apply your changes there.

Throughout your app simply use your subclass instead of `UILabel`.

Even in interface builder you can do this - just change the "Class" to your custom class in the panel on the right.

[image]

Comment: @McMc Excellent! Yeah... we went that way for pretty much everything just because it's the one sure-fire way of getting total control over every UI element.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think this is really possible, but a easy way would just make a IBOutlet for all of the things, then just create a UIFont like `UIFont *customFont = [UIFont alloc] init];` and set the font name for that, then just do label.font = customFont; UIButton.title.font = customFont which makes it slightly easier.