# Default font for iOS app

Tags: ios, fonts, appearance

I already found this article here
[Set a default font for whole iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app)
and I basically have the same question.

I want to set the default font for my whole application **but without having to specify the font size**. I Have different labels with different sizes in my app. I just want to change the font... not the size!

Thanks for helping...

Comment: did you make any progress? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, no.. sorry

I ended up using the default font for now... The requirement for the custom font wasn't that high!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is too late, but for whom who has the same question, there is a two solution for changing the app font without having to specify the font size.:

**The first** is workaround wich is iterating over all the labels in your UIView and change the labels font, check this question and the answers: [How to set a custom font for entire iOS app without specifying size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907761/how-to-set-a-custom-font-for-entire-ios-app-without-specifying-size).

**The Second** is creating a Category for your control:

```
@implementation UILabel (MyCustomLabel)

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    float fontSize = [self.font pointSize];
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyCustomFont" size:fontSize];
}

@end
```