# How can we create a Category of UIfont so using which we can change the font size of every element for different iPhone Device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a Category suppose of UILabel so using which for every device we can change the font size of text as need

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907761/how-to-set-a-custom-font-for-entire-ios-app-without-specifying-size

Comment: KrishnaCA i want to create a class which will support all the element that using UIFont class

Comment: So, you want a custom `UILabel` with a specific `UIFont` right

Comment: the class will be use for all the element which uses UIFont class like textfield,textview,label etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a category class , and add a method like :

```
+(UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName {
    CGFloat fontSize = 14.0;
    if (IS_IPHONE6) {
        fontSize = 15.0;
    }
    if (IS_IPHONE6P) {
        fontSize = 16.0;
    }
    return [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
}
```

About device's size: iphone6 = iphone7 & 6plus = 7plus.

Comment: ya but to change the font of label i have to call every object of UIlabel using i have created but i don't want to do

Comment: oh I see, you need a global method like a define to control the size,  if I have time out of work, I will test some.