# How can I change default font in ios dev

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ios5

After some googling, now I can use custom font. like this:

```
[loginButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:15]];
```

you can not choose custom font in interface build, so you need write code again and again

My question is: how can I change application default font to a custom font

Comment: This post is very vague. Please explain explain what you're trying to do in more detail or provide some code.

Comment: I asked this myself and I find it to be a valid question, also the answer is fine. @allenwei: you should accept it as the right answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set a default font for whole iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app)

Answer (score 5):

i would not alter the system font =)

best way is to create a function that will return the font you wish like this:

```
-(UIFont *)getFont
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:15];
    return font;
}
```

and then wherever you need that font you can do it like this (using your button as example)

```
[loginButton.titleLabel setFont:[self getFont];
```

Comment: It is boring to type it again and again. What's more I can not use custom font in interface builder.

Comment: i'd say this is your best shot.

Comment: better approach is to do it like this "#define FONT_CUSTOME [UIFont fontWithName:@"custom-font-name-here" size:size-here]"