# How can i increase font size of whole application?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I am working on the application that needs to change dynamic font size of all the controls.

[image]

As you seen in the screenshot i have to change the font according to the percentage of font size.

**For Example**

For 100%

```
lbl.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f];
lbl1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.f];
```

For 80%

```
lbl.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
lbl1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.f];
```

For 50%

```
lbl.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f];
lbl1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.f];
```

What's the Best way to do that?

Comment: You should store value of 100% font to any storage. Then recalculate it. It's the best way..

Comment: That i know but fo all the controls. there sould be an easy way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set a default font for whole iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer on my own question. i am not sure is best way to that.

> Enum For the different Font size

```
  typedef enum {
    UIFontCategoryExtraSmall,
    UIFontCategorySmall,
    UIFontCategoryMedium,
    UIFontCategoryLarge,
    UIFontCategoryExtraLarge
} UIFontCategory;

#define FONT_SIZE_KEY @"fontsize"
```

> Category Class of UIFont

```
@interface UIFont (CustomFonSize)

+(UIFont *)preferredFontSizeWithMaxFontSize:(CGFloat )fontSize;

@end



 @implementation UIFont (AvenirContentSize)

+ (UIFont *)preferredFontSizeWithMaxFontSize:(CGFloat )fontSize; {
    // choose the font size
    NSInteger currentFontSize=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:FONT_SIZE_KEY];

    if (currentFontSize==UIFontCategoryExtraSmall) {
        fontSize = fontSize-8;

    } else if (currentFontSize==UIFontCategorySmall) {
        fontSize = fontSize-6;

    } else if (currentFontSize==UIFontCategoryMedium) {
        fontSize = fontSize-4;

    } else if (currentFontSize==UIFontCategoryLarge) {
        fontSize = fontSize-2;

    } else if (currentFontSize==UIFontCategoryExtraLarge) {
        fontSize = fontSize;

    }

    return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];


}
```

Use of the Custom Font Class

```
lbl.font=[UIFont preferredFontSizeWithMaxFontSize:16.0f];
lbl1.font=[UIFont preferredFontSizeWithMaxFontSize:24.f];
```

Comment: Substracting is not the ideal way.. If you want to truly resize font size by percentage then you should probably use `0.8*fontSize` for 80% and `0.6*fontSize` for 60% and so on. [Note: 0.8 = 80%]. I hope u understood my explanation.

Comment: yaa i know but UIFontCategoryExtraSmall with 0.2 it will become too small. so i used Substracting

Comment: That depends on your application user. Any way.. It's good that u found solution. Don't forget to mark your answer after 2 days..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UIAppearance`. [Tutorial link](http://www.ioslearner.com/uiappearance-proxy-protocol-tutorial/)

& Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/sxua/6612459) too.

```
Here's a list of classes that support this feature, in one way or the other.

UIActivityIndicatorView
UIBarButtonItem
UIBarItem
UINavigationBar
UIPopoverController
UIProgressView
UISearchBar
UISegmentedControl
UISlider
UISwitch
UITabBar
UITabBarItem
UIToolbar
UIView
UIViewController
```

***Examples***

**UIActivityIndicatorView:**

```
[[UIActivityIndicatorView appearance] setColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

**UINavigationBar:**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyCustomView class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

**UIBarButtonItem:**

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyCustomView class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor magentaColor]];
```

**UIProgressView:**

```
[[UIProgressView appearance] setProgressTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[[UIProgressView appearance] setTrackTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

**UISegmentedControl:**

```
UIImage *segmentSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment_Selected.png"]
                        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 12)];
UIImage *segmentUnselected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment_Unselected.png"]
                          resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 12)];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected
                                               forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected
                                               forState:UIControlStateSelected
                                             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [UIColor magentaColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                        [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                        [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                        [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier-Oblique" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentedControl_Divider.png"]
                                 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                   rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**UISlider:**

```
[[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Slider_Background.png"]
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Slider_Background.png"]
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Slider_Thumb.png"]
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**UISwitch:**

```
[[UISwitch appearance] setOnTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

**UITabBar:**

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

**UIToolBar:**

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

**UISearchBar:**

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Search_Icon.png"]
                      forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch
                                 state:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Search_Cross.png"]
                      forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear
                                 state:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *searchBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Search_Background.png"];
searchBg = [searchBg stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:searchBg];
```

**EDIT:**

It depends on you. Let's say you should store size of Percentage into `NSUSerDefaults` or other storage. Then by using above code you can calculate the size according to percentage you've stored. Got it?

Comment: if i use appearance then all the label font size will be the same.

Comment: Then use multiple labels (subclassed) & use `UIAppearance`.