# Setting default font for Xcode 5 Interface Builder UIKit components?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Is there a way that every time I get a new UIKit object in Interface builder of Xcode 5 that I could have it automatically have the UI piece use a font of my choosing?

For example, every time I get a new UILabel, it is already using the System font (Helvetica Neue) of size 17, but I would prefer it to be automatically be Avenir Next of size 16, for example.

According to [Mattt's gist on UIAppearance](https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521), UILabel does not have UIAppearance methods as far I can tell, so I wouldn't be able to just do it programmatically.

It's not really a -big- deal or a -show-stopper, but more of just a convenience issue as every UILabel I am using uses the same font family.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know about Interface Builder, but according to this answer you can use the appearance proxy for that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8708191/499350