# Font and colour change throughout the app

Tags: ios7, ios6, fonts, colors, uilabel

I am working on a big demo app in iOS. Now we changing UI for iOS7. i want to reflect font and colour change throughout the app. I want to do it in minimal rework. now i have 15-16 type of font and colour combination which i need to reflect throughout the app.

I know i can create IBOutleCollection. But for each combination creating so many outlet collection is not a good idea.

For ex i have almost 30 customize cell in full app with 3 fix labels and 2-3 extra labels in it. And there are almost 7-8 type of font and colour combination for that 3 fix labels.

This is just an example, count could be more. So creating so many outlet collection does not sound good.

I hope i dont sound stupid.Any Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [UIAppearance](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/)

I suspect your answer is there. Enjoy :)

Comment: I doubt about it. Since everything is in xibs and so customize. I think its more about writing a logic than api.

Comment: Could you clarify your question so I can update my answer? What is stopping you manually setting label fonts and size? Surely that'd be better so you could visually perfect your app?

Comment: Manually setting is not possible since there are lots of labels and customize cell. If i can write something in UIView category and later just attach that in xibs. no code changes.

Comment: Some suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app) might help - it's from a question I asked a while back