# How do I set a default font for the whole OSX/Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app), but for an OSX app, rather than an iOS app.

UIKit and, therefore, UILabel don't appear to be available for non-iOS apps...

Is there a way to do something similar to

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:17.0]];
```

that will work in an OSX app?  Or if I could set a default/global font & color via Xcode, rather than programmatically, that would be great too.

Comment: What do you use for displaying text in OSX? As far as I know, `UILabel` is not available, and I assume you are using `NSTextView`, or `NSText`?

Comment: NSTextField ("Label")

Comment: Good question actually! You should probably put `NSTextField` in the question description as well.

Comment: I can suggest one workaround for this issue. You can write an extension to the Label class and in the awakeFromNib you can assign your desired font and color.