# Create and reuse text style in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

In my iOS application, I would like to define text style with font name, font size, color etc. (same as in `CSS`) and reuse it everywhere in my code.

I tried to find it in Storyboard without any luck. Do you know any way to achieve it?

Comment: Look into `NSAttributedString` - you can define attributes and then apply them to ranges within a string. Note that if you use `UIFont` in the answers given and if you set a specific font size then you will break `Dynamic Type` on iOS. Use `preferredFontForTextStyle:` on `UIFont` rather than `fontWithName:size:`

Answer (score 0):

Here's method for doing this programmatically.
You can set global appearance settings for each class. It's done using **UIAppearance** proxy, available since iOS 5.
By calling this code:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:17.0]];
```

Somewhere at the start of your app, you'll set this font for **UILabel**s, that would be created later.
There are same **UIAppearance** interfaces for UINavigationBar, and some other classes.

**P.S.** There's a bad situation here, you'll still have to set font size everywhere, since I think you don't want to have same size everywhere...
So, another way is to create category for **UIFont**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIFont (SytemFontOverride)
@end

@implementation UIFont (SytemFontOverride)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:fontSize];
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

Took that answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977354/2390305) thread. Don't forget to set plus there :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create style for text in iOS like you do in CSS.
Only solution I would suggest is create a new class for the label, which inherits from UILabel, than create a class method which defines the font for it like this:

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make sub-class of UILabel and override methods like `awakeFromNib`, `-(id)init`, `-(id)initWithFrame`, etc. In these methods you can call a common method where you can customise your label.

On storyBoard, you can drag and drop label and change its class from `UILabel` to your `Custom Class`

```
-(id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) 
   {
       [self customiseLabel];
   }

   return self;
}

-(void)customiseLabel
{
   self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
}
```

Similarly you override other methods also. Doing as shown, you don't need to customise your label all the time.