# Weird swift behaviour on UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Scenario:
I'm setting the text font and size for my **UITextField**.
They also have placeholders.
**The code bellow is in my UIViewController:**

```
        let font = UIFont(name: "FlamaSemicondensed-Book", size: 18)

        let attributesDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: DefaultSystemColor.DarkRed]

        // Textfileds without borders (and placeholders)
        UsernameTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
        UsernameTextField.font = font
        UsernameTextField.textColor = DefaultSystemColor.DarkRed
        UsernameTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email", attributes: attributesDictionary)
```

I'm configuring (in AppDelegate) a global UI setting, that formats all of my **UILabels** for a certain font size.
**The code bellow is in my GlobalUISettings class:**

```
    let font = UIFont(name: "FlamaSemicondensed-Book", size: 13)!
    var labelAppearace = UILabel.appearance()
    labelAppearace.font = font
```

What's weird in here:

When this UITextField is selected and I'm typing the format is the one I set for the text field (the placeholder are OK too).

But when I leave the field it assumes the behaviour of the UILabel.

I know that because if I comment the UILabel format the textField works properly.

Does anybody have any idea why does it happens?

Comment: For some strange reason, none of UILabel's properties are tagged as `UIAppearance_Selector`, which means you can get unexpected behaviour when using them. Just a heads up.

Comment: So it's probably a bug on UIKit? I'm quite new to swift. I was just trying to figure out what I was doing wrong :-)

Comment: No, it's not a bug. `UITextfield` is basically a `UILabel` while not editing, and it follows the appearance traits of it, if you are using an appearance selector, narrow it down to your requirements using `[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:(__unsafe_unretained Class<UIAppearanceContainer>)>, nil];` instead of the more generic one.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `let font` to `let labelFont` because 'font' is global. It might be affecting.

Comment: I have a global configuration (UILabel) and in my UIViewController I'm setting the UITextField. They aren't in the same class.

Comment: Check this post on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app

Comment: My point here is to figure out how formatting an UILabel is affecting the UITextField setup.

Comment: Are you using the UITextField delegates ?

Comment: No, I'm not. My UIViewController have 2 textFields and a btn.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior.

To change the font of the placeholder you have to add the `NSFontAttributeName` attribute with the desired font as value to the `NSAttributedString` you assign to `attributedPlaceholder`.

Example:

```
let attributesDictionary = [
    NSFontAttributeName: font,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: DefaultSystemColor.DarkRed
]
```

Comment: I have no problems setting the font. My problem is when I leave the TextField it assumes the behaviour of the UILabel.

Comment: That's because changing the appearance of ALL UILabels is not a good idea in any case. This also affects system UI in the app and internal views of other controls like UITextField and UIButton.

Comment: It kind of makes sense. I would expect a different behaviour when I set the appearence of a control, but thanks anyway