# Default Font for whole Mac App

Tags: macos, cocoa, fonts

I am working on Cocoa App (Swift 1.2 in XCode 6.3.2)
I am want to try out different Look and feel of various fonts.
Is there a convenient way to set the default font of entire app.

Same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app) for iOS, but does not work for Cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

Up to now no you cannot do this. 
There are some parts of AppKit that do not let you set fonts or stylings at all. This is to keep the user experience consistent as possible in a multi window environment.

You could try to go and set fonts for most of your views, controls, menus and windows, but the thing you will run into is that Cocoa comes with a design per OS version where UI elements expect to be certain sizes in many places and expect certain fonts and metrics.