# How to change iOS system font dynamically but remember original font?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uifont, objective-c-category

I am able to change the language of my iOS app on the fly without terminating the app. However, I want to change the system fonts on the fly too because the standard Helvetica Neue fonts don't look good with some languages. I'm going to use a category from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977354/1938889) and include it in my `.pch`:

```
@implementation UIFont (SytemFontOverride)
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"FONT NAME" size:fontSize];
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
@end
```

However, when in English I want to use the *default* system fonts which vary slightly from iOS version and device. **My question is how can I achieve something like this**

```
static UIFont *defaultRegularFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
```

so I can reuse it when the app switches back to English like this

```
+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    ...
    // If English
    return [UIFont fontWithName:[defaultRegularFont fontName] size:fontSize];
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ndmeiri "How to change iOS system font dynamically but remember original font?"

Comment: Try using `NSUserDefaults`, then save your original font there.

Comment: @0yeoj Please write up a solution and let's see if it works