# Set a custom default font for whole Xamarin.iOS app?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a custom font that I want to set as the default font for the whole Xamarin.iOS app without specifying the size. How can I achieve this?

I already found [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app), however this refers to a non-Xamarin iOS app.

Comment: hi, did you find any solution for this? i can enable fonts for Label, entry etc(Xamarin.Forms Attributes)... but not for titles & content of dialog boxes, list in pickers n many more places like that(Internal iOS attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass each control you want affected (Entry, Label) etc and add a custom property for size. From there create a custom renderer in iOS where you set the font to be used by all but also pass the custom property for size each type you call the control. Here is a blog article I wrote a while ago on this topic [Making Custom Renderers in Xamarin.Forms More Scalable](http://darrellbooker.tumblr.com/post/101951741293/making-custom-renderers-in-xamarinforms-more)