# How to change the default fontFamily in react-native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Can I set a default fontFamily in my app (iOS and Android)??

I don't want set it in each screen.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is from the native side of things.  See here:

[Set a default font for whole iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app)

and

[Is it possible to set a custom font for entire of application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application/16883281#16883281)

Although, if you use the library [Cairn](https://github.com/adamterlson/cairn) (disclaimer: I wrote it) it's trivial.  Simply define your global text style and extend from it everywhere.  Cairn makes all global stuff reusable while not breaking component-specific overrides and extensions.

```
// styles.js
import { createStylesheet } from 'react-native';
import cairn from 'cairn';

export default cairn({
    text: {
        fontFamily: '...'
    }
}, (styles) => createStylesheet(styles));
```

Then extend those global styles in your component and apply to your text element:

```
// components/MyComponent.js

import styleContext from '../styles';

const style = styleContext.extend({
    'text.header': {
        fontSize: 30
    }
});

export default const MyComponent = () => (
    // Spreads style={[styleContext.text, style['text.header']]}
    <Text {...style('text.header')}>Header!</Text>
);
```