# Changing all UILabel fonts in app depending on current font weight using Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uilabel, swift4

In Swift 3, I used the following to replace all fonts in BOLD to MEDIUM in AppDelegate:

```
UILabel.appearance().substituteFontNameBold = "HelveticaNeue-Medium"
```

And by adding this extension to UILabel :

```
extension UILabel {
    var substituteFontNameBold : String {
        get { return self.font.fontName }
        set {
            if self.font.fontName.contains("Bold") {
                self.font = UIFont(name: newValue, size: self.font.pointSize)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the upgrade to Swift 4, I get a "***fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***" on

```
if self.font.fontName.contains("Bold") {
```

How can I continue to replace all fonts in BOLD to MEDIUM in labels with Swift 4?

Comment: Probably `self` (UILabel) is nil at this point. Try to call it at later stage.

Comment: For some reason some answers as well as my responses to those answers were deleted (oO ?) :
The person suggested replacing self with UILabel.appearance() : this didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Based on Sandy Chapman's answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28440649/5778002

Fully working on Swift 3.
On Swift 4 : self.font returns nil

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue. I tried to do it in viewDidAppear but still nil value for self.font.pointSize

Comment: Gave up. I changed all the fonts in the storyboard directly via ctrl-F ...

Comment: Having same issue now, dont really like subclass or manually change...but this doesnt work anymore, weird

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Swift 4.0**

This will help you set custom font for all of your UILabel, UIButton, etc. Simply create a extension and replace with this.

```
var appFontName       = "Gudea" //Please put your REGULAR font name
var appFontBoldName   = "Gudea" //Please put your BOLD font name
var appFontItalicName = "Gudea" //Please put your ITALIC font name

extension UIFont {

@objc class func mySystemFont(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: appFontName, size: size)!
}

@objc class func myBoldSystemFont(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: appFontBoldName, size: size)!
}

@objc class func myItalicSystemFont(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: appFontItalicName, size: size)!
}

@objc convenience init(myCoder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    if let fontDescriptor = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "UIFontDescriptor") as? UIFontDescriptor {
        if let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.fontAttributes[UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName(rawValue: "NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute")] as? String {
            var fontName = ""
            switch fontAttribute {
            case "CTFontRegularUsage":
                fontName = appFontName
            case "CTFontEmphasizedUsage", "CTFontBoldUsage":
                fontName = appFontBoldName
            case "CTFontObliqueUsage":
                fontName = appFontItalicName
            default:
                fontName = appFontName
            }
            self.init(name: fontName, size: fontDescriptor.pointSize)!
        }
        else {
            self.init(myCoder: aDecoder)
        }
    }
    else {
        self.init(myCoder: aDecoder)
    }
}

class func overrideInitialize() {
    if self == UIFont.self {
        let systemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(systemFont(ofSize:)))
        let mySystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(mySystemFont(ofSize:)))
        method_exchangeImplementations(systemFontMethod!, mySystemFontMethod!)

        let boldSystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(boldSystemFont(ofSize:)))
        let myBoldSystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(myBoldSystemFont(ofSize:)))
        method_exchangeImplementations(boldSystemFontMethod!, myBoldSystemFontMethod!)

        let italicSystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(italicSystemFont(ofSize:)))
        let myItalicSystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(myItalicSystemFont(ofSize:)))
        method_exchangeImplementations(italicSystemFontMethod!, myItalicSystemFontMethod!)

        let initCoderMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIFontDescriptor.init(coder:))) // Trick to get over the lack of UIFont.init(coder:))
        let myInitCoderMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIFont.init(myCoder:)))
        method_exchangeImplementations(initCoderMethod!, myInitCoderMethod!)
    }
}
}
```

**Update: Swift3.2**

replace this line:

```
if let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.fontAttributes[UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName(rawValue: "NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute")] as? String {
```

with:

```
if let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.fontAttributes["NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"] as? String {
```

Comment: Anyway, block if self == UIFont.self {} is useless.

Answer (score 6):

I have found the fix for this, you basically have to add `@objc` to make it works, after added it no more nil value

```
@objc public var substituteFontName : String
```

Comment: Thanks!! I can't really comprehend why, but it works. Do you have a theory why this works? @Tj3n

Comment: @barley It seems like the `UIAppearance` only able to read the function (maybe via KVC) if it's exposed to objc runtime, the keyword did that. Maybe Apple haven't added support for this feature in Swift yet.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah that kind of convinces me, but kind of not... `UIApperance` can certainly read `substituteFontName` because it runs the `set` method inside it. But it somehow cannot access `UILabel.font` attribute if `substituteFontName` is not exposed as Obj-C interface..

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by overriding the system font as follow:

```
import UIKit

struct AppFontName {
    static let regular = "DINNextLTArabic-Regular"
}

extension UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName {
    static let nsctFontUIUsage =
        UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName(rawValue: "NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute")
}

extension UIFont {

    @objc class func mySystemFont(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: AppFontName.regular, size: size)!
    }

    @objc convenience init(myCoder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        if let fontDescriptor = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "UIFontDescriptor") as? UIFontDescriptor {
                let fontName = AppFontName.regular
                self.init(name: fontName, size: fontDescriptor.pointSize)!

        } else {
            self.init(myCoder: aDecoder)
        }
    }

    class func overrideInitialize() {
        if self == UIFont.self {
            let systemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(systemFont(ofSize:)))
            let mySystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(mySystemFont(ofSize:)))
            method_exchangeImplementations(systemFontMethod!, mySystemFontMethod!)


            let initCoderMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIFontDescriptor.init(coder:))) // Trick to get over the lack of UIFont.init(coder:))
            let myInitCoderMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIFont.init(myCoder:)))
            method_exchangeImplementations(initCoderMethod!, myInitCoderMethod!)
        }
    }
}
```

and in appDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    UIFont.overrideInitialize()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Anyway, block if self == UIFont.self {} is useless.

Comment: Perfect job! Works for the entry app, many thanks!