# How to update font family of complete ios app globally

Tags: swift4, font-family, xcode9.1

I am working on an app and it very painful and time consuming to update font family for each label and other text elements used in xcode.

Is there any way we can update the font family of all label, text fields etc globally without changing the font-size.

I used this code in swift 3 and worked perfectly

[Set a default font for whole iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app#answer-28440649)

```
extension UILabel {

    var substituteFontName : String {
        get { return self.font.fontName }
        set { self.font = UIFont(name: newValue, size: self.font.pointSize) }
    }
}
```

but in swift 4 it shows this error

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
on line

```
set { self.font = UIFont(name: newValue, size: self.font.pointSize) }
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a default font for whole iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app)

Comment: This solution is no longer working in Swift 4

Comment: Describe "not working"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app#answer-28440649

Comment: This answer suits my requirement. I tried it in swift 3 and it worked fine. Once i upgraded to swift 4 it shows error.

Comment: I have just updated my question for this.