# add Objective C instance Variables in category

Tags: objective-c

I know in objective c you can not add instance variable in category of interface. that is ok but today i see something i can not figure it out ,(why is this behavior right?)

```
@interface XXXX:NSObject

@end

@interface XXXX(){

@private

    int x;
}

@end
```

why can i add add instance variable in empty () category , also why no one mention in in the internet.

Thanks All

Comment: The empty category is a class extension. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136124/class-extension-vs-class-category for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can add instance variables to anonymous categories/class extensions (Using just `()` for the category name), because they are essentially just a private extension of the main interface, and there can only be one.

However you cannot add new instance variables with named categories. You can make use of [Associative References](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) to work around this however.

Comment: Actually, you can do this as of Apple's latest Objective-C language revisions. But you can't if you're still using the 32-bit Mac ABI, as it's not able to accommodate the new language features.

Comment: Is that for all categories or just anonymous/class categories?

Comment: this code complies with Xcode 4.1 for ios with not problems.
i just want to know why is this allowed is there any resource i can find this info in.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can add instance variables to class categories. But not named ones.

Comment: actually i found good info here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

Comment: It's not a category, it's an extension. Class extensions can do this; categories *cannot*.

Comment: The syntactic difference is that an extension has no name, i.e. `()`, while a category has a name. (Apart from the value assigned to `__func__`, there's no practical difference between a method in a category and one in an extension.)

Comment: Not true;  there are a number of significant differences between a category and a class extension.  Extensions can promote readonly->readwrite in properties, can add ivars, can add synthesize properties, and are true extensions of @interface.  Categories are informal additions to a class, interface or interface+implementation, but cannot do the above.