# readonly public, readwrite private property

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, encapsulation

I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837565/objective-c-private-public-properties-making-a-property-readonly-for-outsi), but am not completely clear in iOS7 given the Programming guide says you can leave out the `@synthesise` keyword for properties.

I want to have a `@property` that is `readonly` externally, but `readwrite` internally. Can I use just the `@property` keyword like this?

EDIT: What would be considered more correct, or at least more idiomatic, of the answers provided. To have a separate `readwrite` property in a Class extension or access the ivar directly in the implementation?

EDIT: To show that I am using a Class Extension, as suggested in answers.

```
//.h
@interface CACustomerAuthenticator : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *username;
@end

//.m
@interface CACustomerAuthenticator ()
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *username;
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readonly` is enough.

Using

```
@synthesize username = _someVar;
```

You are allowed to write in `username` accessing `_someVar`. If there's no `synthesize`, then

```
@synthesize username = _username;
```

is automatically generated.

Comment: Are you saying I don't need anything in my Class Extension, only the readonly property in the Interface?

Comment: Would I then need to access the _username directly in my implementation rather than via the accessor?

Comment: Yes but you have to set the username property through the ivar _username

Comment: Thank you. Which would you consider more idiomatic, using the ivar directly or a separate readwrite property in a Class Extension?

Comment: I would go for the ivar, but I think it's only a matter of programming style

Comment: I'd go for the property method. It's neater and hides the actual implementation details. You may want to write a custom setter that does more than just set the backing store, you may wish to set the variable in a block, in which case it's easier to pass a weak reference to self, rather than writing self->_username, etc.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do this you re-declare the property in a class extension.

For example, if you have a class called MyClass:

**MyClass.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *username;
```

**MyClass.m**

```
// Create a class extension before the @implementation section
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *username;
@end
```

Now the public interface has the property as readonly, and the private interface has it as readwrite. And you don't need to @synthesize the property, the backing iVar is available as `_username` by default.

Comment: This is a better answer than above, because you cannot access _ivars in blocks without creating self/retain loops unless you somehow redeclare them as __weak