# Properties in Objective C (readwrite for self and readonly for others)

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

In a iOS app, I needed a property which is **readonly for other classes but readwrite for self calls**. So I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837565/objective-c-private-public-properties-making-a-property-readonly-for-outsi) and formed my code as,

In .h:

```
@interface TheClassName : NSObject {
     NSString* str;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString* str;
@end
```

In .m:

```
@interface TheClassName()
@property(nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSString* str;
@end

@implementation TheClassName
-(id)init {
     if(self = [super init]) {
          str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
     }
     return self;
}
@end
```

This procedure is valid also according to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW6). But I tried experimenting on my code and the problem started.

All I did is ignored the **@interface** part in the **.m file** with respect to **Seva Alekseyev**'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837565/objective-c-private-public-properties-making-a-property-readonly-for-outsi), but compiler showed no warning or error when I used it as `str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"]` in the **.m file** !!

I mean, the property is set to be `readonly`, so the statement should have produced an error, but it didn't. **WHY??**

**NOTE:** I am using Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: Follow trojanfoe's advice and _always_ start instance variables with an underscore to avoid that stupid kind of mistake. Also turn warnings on so the compiler can tell you about stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
```

doesn't call the property setter, it references the instance variable you defined directly:

```
@interface TheClassName : NSObject {
     NSString* str;
}
```

and, by default, the backing instance variable will be called `_str`, so you should remove that instance variable definition and refer to `_str` directly (if you don't want to create a `readwrite` version of the property).  As it currently stands the property `str` won't refer to the instance variable `str` without explicitly using a `@synthesize str = str;` statement.