# Illegal redeclaration of property in class extension 'AppDelegate' (attribute must be 'readwrite', while its primary must be 'readonly')

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I moved this line:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
```

into a class extension in my App Delegate but now get this error:

```
Illegal redeclaration of property in class extension 'AppDelegate' (attribute must be 'readwrite', while its primary must be 'readonly')
```

The full code from the `.m` file looks like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate()
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@end
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you provide just a little more context? Try adding the `@interface ...` lines and show the original class definition of this property in addition to the definition included in the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Your codes you pasted are weigh less to analyze the problem.

However, from my guessing, probably you can delete the declaration from .m file.

You can find more in the following link.

[Objective-C : (private / public properties) making a property readonly for outside class calls and readwrite for self calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837565/objective-c-private-public-properties-making-a-property-readonly-for-outsi)