# readwrite and readonly mutually exclusive

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, properties

How can I go about achieving this

- Property has to be readwrite for inner implementation in class
- Property has to be readonly for external interaction to instances of the class

Comment: In Swift or in Objective-C?

Comment: What language? Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: If Swift - duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708439/swift-readonly-external-readwrite-internal-property?rq=1

Comment: If Objective-C - duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837565/objective-c-private-public-properties-making-a-property-readonly-for-outsi

Comment: both the languages would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In Objective-C:

#### MyObject.h

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString *myProperty;

@end
```

#### MyObject.m

```
// Class extension
@interface MyObject ()

// Redeclare property read-write
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSString *myProperty;

@end

@implementation MyObject

...
```

## In Swift:

```
class MyObject {

    private(set) var myProperty: String

    ...
```

Comment: Do we really need answers to such a duplicate?

Comment: Well, “need” would be putting it strongly.

Comment: But next time the question comes up, you can say it's a duplicate of this one without worrying about the language. ;^)

Comment: @robmayoff - I don't understand the SWIFT part

Comment: It's just a regular Swift property declaration, with the prefix `private(set)` to indicate that the setter can only be called by the methods of `MyObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like the following example

In your .h:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSDate* theDate;
```

In your .m:

```
@interface TheClassName()
@property(nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSDate* theDate;
@end
```